# If $z\in C_A\cap \overline{W(A)}$, why $z\in \partial W(A)$?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $\mathcal{B}(F)$ the algebra of all bounded linear operators on a complex Hilbert space $F$.

Let $A\in\mathcal{B}(F)$ and consider
$$W(A)=\{\langle Ax,x\rangle:\;x \in F,\;\;\|x\|=1\},$$
and
$$C_A:=\{z\in \mathbb{C}:\;|z|=\|A\| \}.$$

> If $z\in C_A\cap \overline{W(A)}$, why $z\in \partial W(A)$ ?

I think it suffices to prove that $z$ does not lie in the interior of $W(A)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First,
$$
W(A) \subset \{ z: \ |z| \le \|A\|\}.
$$
$C_A$ is the boundary of the latter set, so any point in $C_A$ cannot be an interior point of $W(A)$.

Comment: Could you please explain me why any point in $C_A$ cannot be an interior point of $W(A)$? Thanks.

Comment: Because otherwise there would be an open ball around such a $z$ containing points with absolute value larger than $\|A\|$